# Do superconducter wires still have low resistance above their transition temperature?

Tags: electrical-resistance, superconductivity

Superconducting wires have almost zero resistance below their transistion temperature. But do they still have resistance better than other wires above that temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Elemental supercoductors most usually used are aluminium, tin, lead, niobium. You can check their conductivities and decide.

A much better example to answer your question are cuprates. YBCO is a superconductor below ~70K, but is not really a conductor at all in the normal state. I have personally seen thin YBCO wires being blown (visible damage) as a result of quenching. The way it happens is that you have large current flowing through the superconucting wire. If the current becomes too large the wire, at some place, goes into normal state. The resistance rapidly increases, whilst current is still flowing, which leads to rapid heating and destruction of a small segment of wire.

If you want more info, see work on fault current limiters based on YBCO (e.g. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1325035). However, those guys generally try to avoid destroying the superconducting wire.

Comment: YBCO is definitely a conductor in the normal state.

Comment: Appologies if I was not precise. The resitance of normal state YBCO was large (factor of 5-10 as I remember) compared to other materials I was working with (e.g. niobium in normal state), so we colloquially called a 'bad conductor' etc.

Comment: So "not really a conductor at all" is not imprecise. It is wrong.

Comment: Agreed ........

Answer (score 0):

No. Nothing beats silver and copper wires.

Comment: Consider backing this up with some quantitative data or an authoritative reference.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Should be general knowledge.

Comment: Everything on this webpage is. Do as you wish; but do note that your answer was flagged for deletion, whence my comment.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform If the admins think that this does not answer the question, just delete it. But I do not think the site has wikipedia rules.